# XP can't read data from transferred HD

Tags: windows-xp, permissions, data-recovery, crash

Computer A, running XP, died.

XP was installed on a fresh HD in computer B.

Slaved data-backup HD from A was installed as slave on B. B will not read it; shows only 2 folders, Recycler and System Volume Info. All of these are older machines with IDE drives.

What's going on & how can I read/transfer the data from the transferred drive?

This was only a trial run. Actually I will need to transfer the master HD from A - which has XP on it - and read from its data partition because (blush) the backup drive was not up to date.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like a permissions issue here. I would wager the data's still there; however, you cannot see it because it has a different security identifier. You need to take ownership of the disk. This Microsoft KB [article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308421) shows how to do it for a file or folder, and the principle is the same for an entire disk.